External monitor via HDMI will not display; xrandr says HDMI disconnected; NVIDIA GPU
I had Ubuntu 22.04 and when I attach HDMI cable to hp external monitor, the monitor says no signal and then goes to sleep. I checked HDMI cable on another Ubuntu computer and it worked.  I connected my Ubuntu computer to another monitor and get same message on screen.  Whats strange is that everything was working fine and I made no changes to any setting.  I update the computer whenever there is a notice so its possible it was some update but I dont keep track of every update since they come quite frequently. I upgraded to 24.04 and no change.  It is not a bad monitor as I used my friend's Ubuntu computer and connected same HDMI cable to it and it properly displayed.
I am a basic Ubuntu user and when I read other posts with similar issues and their suggested solutions, those solutions are WAY above what Im capable of.  I need to have just a simple linux command to copy/paste into terminal.  I can edit configuration files but simple ones. Thats about my the extent of my Linux capability.
I would appreciate any feedback.  I have been able to get by with Ubuntu for nearly 10 years with many issues solved by finding commands to copy/paste but this is the first time I am seriously considering just going Apple (ill never use Windows - Id rather never use a computer).  This is a tough one for me.  I tried just about every posted solution out there but still here.
**inxi -Fxz**

CPU:
  Info: 14-core (6-mt/8-st) model: 12th Gen Intel Core i9-12900H bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP arch: Alder Lake rev: 3 cache: L1: 1.2 MiB L2: 11.5 MiB
    L3: 24 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 422 high: 845 min/max: 400/4900:5000:3800 cores: 1: 400
    2: 400 3: 400 4: 400 5: 400 6: 400 7: 400 8: 400 9: 845 10: 400 11: 400
    12: 400 13: 400 14: 400 15: 400 16: 400 17: 400 18: 400 19: 400 20: 400
    bogomips: 116736
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] vendor: Dell
    driver: i915 v: kernel arch: Gen-12.2 bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA104M [Geforce RTX 3070 Ti Laptop GPU] vendor: Dell
    driver: nvidia v: 535.183.01 arch: Ampere bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Device-3: Realtek Integrated_Webcam_HD driver: uvcvideo type: USB
    bus-ID: 3-7:4
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: EGL Message: No EGL data available.
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 vendor: nvidia v: 535.183.01 glx-v: 1.4
    direct-render: yes renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio vendor: Dell
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl bus-ID: 00:1f.3
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA104 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.1
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-40-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active

    **xrandr --prop | grep "HDMI"**

HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    ConnectorType: HDMI 
        supported: Unknown, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI, DP, Wireless, Native
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        supported: Unknown, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI, DP, Wireless, Native
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        supported: Unknown, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI, DP, Wireless, Native
HDMI-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

    **aplay -l**

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 31: HDA Analog Deep Buffer (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

NVIDIA Settings

Operating System: Linux-x86_64
NVIDIA Driver Version: 535.183.01
NVML Version: 12.535.183.01
X Server Information
Server Version Number: 11.0
Server Vendor Version: 1.21.1.11(12101011)
NV-CONTROL Version: 1.29
Screens: 1
GPUs: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti Laptop GPU (GPU0)
Displays: None
Recovered GPU Errors: 0
Xvideo Settings
Currently synced to display: Unknown
Sync to this display device: Auto

Two different computers tell you they can not talk to the monitor? Have you considered bad monitor?

Ah, yes, good point.  I forgot to mention - I used my friend's Ubuntu computer and connected same HDMI cable to it and it properly displayed.

Now you are changing the info. No one can help you if the question has wrong or changing info. Please edit the question and make sure all the info is correct and complete.

i took it to Tech2U but they couldnt figure it out.  The techincian admitted not an expert in Linux.  His guess was a bad HDMI port.  So now just using USB-c to HDMI adapter and it works fine.  I have been humbled by the great Ubuntu God.
